# Is there a shortcut to repeat the last StyleCop scan

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, stylecop

I'm sorting out my StyleCop violations a file at a time.

Is there a quick way of repeating the last scan without right-clicking on the file in the Solution Explorer and selecting Run StyleCop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard. There, you can find the "RunStyleCop" command and assign any shortcut keys you want.

Comment: For future readers, the command I had to assign was: ProjectandSolutionContextMenus.SolutionFolder.RunStyleCop